# Issues with writing a dataframe to a xlsx file in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am very new to R. I am trying to write a bunch of dataframes that are one row each to an xlsx file, but it is only writing to two cells in the file. Any assistance would be much appreciated!

```
files <- list.files(path="C:/Users/owner/Desktop/LONG_TABLE_DATA", pattern="*.xlsx", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)

n=1

lapply(files, function(x) {tall = 
     read.table("94__U036-Pool00_trimmed_Sample1_S5_L001_R1_001_trimmed_Sample1_S5_L001_R2_001_500kb_SORT_norm.num.txt", 
     sep = "\t", dec = ".", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
     colClasses=c("NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL",
          "NULL", "NULL", "numeric", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL")) 

tp=t(tall)

data.frame(tp)

write.table(tp,file = "stuff.txt", append = FALSE, col.names = FALSE,row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: `append = FALSE` in `write.table` will overwrite everything that was previously saved in your "stuff.txt" file. Use `append=TRUE` to include results without deleting previous data.

Comment: You also never closed the bracket in the function you used in `lapply` (probably a typo) and I think you meant to use `tall=read.table(x)` instead of using a specific file.